# Transfer Gridview content to a Crystal report

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, crystal-reports

I have a gridview which contains data from a SQL database, and a textbox which holds a string variable. What I want to do is, I want to transfer the content of the gridview and the string variable into a Crystal Report.

This is a sample of what I want the crystal report to turn out.

```
                                 SAMPLE HEADING
         Name: (string variable)
            Quantity       |            Boxes              |   Item Name
               5           |              2                |   Sample Data 1
               2           |              1                |   Sample Data 2
               1           |              5                |   Sample Data 3
```

The Quantity, Boxes, Item Name are fields from my gridview which I want to transfer to a crystal report, and the (string variable) is the one that my textbox holds.

Comment: Add your grid view datasourec as report datasource

Comment: @Al-3sli how can i access that? on what form should i do that? in the form of the crystal report viewer or in the form of the gridview itself?